# convert decimal to a string - in thousands with rounding

Tags: c#, string, formatting, currency

I need to convert a decimal to currency string so i did this:

```
CultureInfo usa = new CultureInfo("en-US");
NumberFormatInfo nfi = usa.NumberFormat;

nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
myValueFormated = String.Format(nfi, "{0:C}", value);
```

It removed decimal places, gave me a comma separator for thousands and and currency symbol.
But I also need to display that number in thousands, rounded.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the rounding bit yourself:

```
value = Math.Round(value / 1000);
```